# $FINITE_{TM}$ is not Turing-reducible to $A_{MT}$

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability, oracle-machines

$FINITE_{TM} = \{\langle M \rangle\mid M\text{ is a TM and }L(M)\text{ is finite}\}$

$A_{MT} = \{\langle M,w \rangle \mid M\text{ is a TM and }M\text{ accepts }w\}$

I'm trying to prove that $FINITE_{TM}$ is not Turing-reducible to $A_{MT}$ by contradiction.

Supposing it is, I get that there's an oracle Turing machine $H^x$ that decides $FINITE_{TM}$ for $x = A_{MT}$, but I have no idea how to reach a contradiction using this.